# PySide Signal argument can't be retrieved from QML

Tags: python, qml, pyside, pyside2

I've noticed that QML can receive a signal emitted from Python by using the Connections object. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get that object to receive the arguments of that signal.

I've created a minimal test case that demonstrates what I want to do:

min.py

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtDeclarative
import sys

# init Qt
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

# set up the signal
class Signaller(QtCore.QObject):
    emitted = QtCore.Signal(str)

signaller = Signaller()

# Load the QML
qt_view = QtDeclarative.QDeclarativeView()
context = qt_view.rootContext()
context.setContextProperty('signaller', signaller)
qt_view.setResizeMode(QtDeclarative.QDeclarativeView.SizeRootObjectToView)
qt_view.setSource('min.qml')
qt_view.show()

# launch the signal
signaller.emitted.emit("Please display THIS text!")

# Run!
app.exec_()
```

And min.qml

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    width:300; height:100

    Text {
        id: display
        text: "No signal yet detected!"

        Connections {
            target: signaller
            onEmitted: {
                display.text = "???" //how to get the argument?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Qt 4.8, PySide doesn't handle signal parameter names at all.

But you can create a QML signal with named parameters and connect your python signal to it using Javascript:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    width:300; height:100


    Text {
        id: display
        text: "No signal yet detected!"

        signal reemitted(string text)
        Component.onCompleted: signaller.emitted.connect(reemitted)

        onReemitted: {
          display.text = text;        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As of Qt for Python versions 5.12.5, 5.13.1 it is working the same as in PyQt:

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import Signal

sumResult = Signal(int, arguments=['sum'])
sumResult.emit(42)
```

QML:

```
onSumResult: console.log(sum)
```

Comment: Not working here in PySide2 (5.14.2), Getting error  "Cannot assign to non-existent property".

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me on PySide2 5.15.0

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i can't comment since i need to have higher reputation. 
In response to the "Cannot assign to non-existent property", it's caused by the order in which you initialize your application. 
Your root context object needs to be created before the engine.

Ok:

`context = Context()
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("context", context)`

Not ok:

`engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
context = Context()
engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("context", context)`