# Connect python signal to QML ui slot with PySide2

Tags: python, qml, qt-signals, pyside2

I've just started playing with PySide2 and QML for an upcoming project and I immediately stumbled on a problem: How do I connect a signal emitted by a python class (that inherits from QObject) to a slot in a .qml file?
For example: I have a QThread (python class) that generates a couple of xy coordinates every 50 milliseconds. I want to add the generated couple to a LineSeries defined in a QML file, in order to generate an oscilloscope-like plot.

The question is probably really basic and dumb, but I really need some help.

Best regards

Lando

EDIT 4:

I've found a solution, but I do not really like it. Can you suggest me (if it exists) a more elegant way to do it?

Code for Python:

```
class Manager(QObject):

    dataReady = Signal(float,float)

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self._currX = 0
        self._currY = 0
        self._delay = 0.5
        self._multiplier = 1.0
        self._power = 1.0
        self._xIncrement = 1.0
        self._starter = False
        self._threader = None

    @Property(bool)
    def starter(self):
        return self._starter

    @starter.setter
    def setStarter(self, val):
        print("New val: {0}, oldVal: {1}".format(val,self._starter))
        if self._starter == val:
            return

        self._starter = val
        if val:
            self.start()
        else:
            self.stop()

    @Property(float)
    def multiplier(self):
        return self._multiplier

    @multiplier.setter
    def setMultiplier(self, val):
        if self._multiplier == val:
            return
        print(val)
        self._multiplier = val

    @Property(int)
    def power(self):
        return self._power

    @power.setter
    def setPower(self, val):
        if self._power == val:
            return
        print(val)
        self._power = val

    @Property(float)
    def delay(self):
        return self._delay

    @delay.setter
    def setDelay(self, val):
        if self._delay == val:
            return
        print(val)
        self._delay = val

    @Property(float)
    def xIncrement(self):
        return self._xIncrement

    @xIncrement.setter
    def setXIncrement(self, val):
        if self._xIncrement == val:
            return
        print(val)
        self._xIncrement = val

    def generatePoint(self):
        self._currX += self._xIncrement
        self._currY = self._multiplier*(self._currX**self._power)

        return self._currX,self._currY

    def stop(self):
        self._goOn = False
        if self._threader is not None:
            while self._threader.isRunning():
                sleep(0.1)

    def start(self):
        self._goOn = True
        self._threader = Threader(core=self.core)
        self._threader.start()

    def core(self):
        while self._goOn:
            x,y = self.generatePoint()
            print([x,y])
            self.dataReady.emit(x,y)
            sleep(self._delay)

class Threader(QThread):

    def __init__(self,core,parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self,parent)
        self._core = core
        self._goOn = False

    def run(self):
        self._core()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ["QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE"] = "Material"
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    manager = Manager()
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    ctx = engine.rootContext()
    ctx.setContextProperty("Manager", manager)
    engine.load('main.qml')
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Code for QML:

```
ApplicationWindow {
id: mainWindow
width:640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Simple ui")
visible: true
locale:locale

property var controlsColor: Material.DeepPurple
property var controlsAccent: Material.BlueGrey
property real x: 0.0
property int controlsElevation: 6
property int paneElevation: 4

function drawPoint(theX,theY){
    console.log(theX);
    mainLine.append(theX,theY)
    if (theX >= testXAxis.max){
        testXAxis.max = theX;
    }
    if (theY >= testYAxis.max){
        testYAxis.max = theY;
    }
    if (theY <= testYAxis.min){
        testYAxis.min = theY;
    }
}

function clearLine(){
    mainLine.clear();
    mainLine.append(0,0);
}

Pane{
    id: mainPanel
    anchors.fill: parent
    //Material.theme: Material.Dark

    RowLayout{
        id: mainRowLO
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 15

        //Chart pane
        Pane{
            id: chartPane
            Material.elevation: paneElevation
            //Material.background: Material.Grey
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.minimumHeight: 200
            Layout.minimumWidth: 400

            ChartView {
                id: testChart
                title: "Line"
                anchors.fill: parent
                antialiasing: true
                LineSeries {
                    id: mainLine
                    name: "LineSeries"
                    axisX: ValueAxis{
                        id: testXAxis
                        min: 0.0
                        max: 2.0
                    }
                    axisY: ValueAxis{
                        id: testYAxis
                        min: 0.0
                        max: 2.0
                    }
                    XYPoint { x: 0; y: 0 }
                }
            }
        }

        Pane{
            id: controlsPane
            Material.elevation: paneElevation
            //Material.background: Material.Grey
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.minimumHeight: 200
            Layout.minimumWidth: 200
            Layout.maximumWidth: 200

            ColumnLayout{
                id: controlsColumnLO
                anchors.fill: parent
                spacing: 40

                Label{
                    id: powerLabel
                    text: "Exponent"
                    Layout.topMargin: 40
                    Layout.leftMargin: 10
                    Layout.rightMargin: 10
                }

                SpinBox{
                    id: powerNum
                    from: 0
                    value: 1
                    to: 5
                    stepSize: 1
                    width: 80
                    validator: DoubleValidator {
                        bottom: Math.min(powerNum.from, powerNum.to)
                        top:  Math.max(powerNum.from, powerNum.to)
                    }
                    Material.foreground: controlsColor
                    Material.accent: controlsAccent
                    Material.elevation: controlsElevation
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.leftMargin: 10
                    Layout.rightMargin: 10
                    editable: true
                    onValueChanged: function(){
                        Manager.power = value;
                    }
                }

                Label{
                    id: multiplierLabel
                    text: "Multiplier"
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.leftMargin: 10
                    Layout.rightMargin: 10
                }

                Slider{
                    id: multiplierSlider
                    from: -50
                    value: 1
                    to: 50
                    Material.foreground: controlsColor
                    Material.accent: controlsAccent
                    Material.elevation: controlsElevation
                    Layout.leftMargin: 10
                    Layout.rightMargin: 10
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    onValueChanged: function(){
                        Manager.multiplier = value;
                    }
                }

                Label{
                    id: multValueLabel
                    text: String(multiplierSlider.value)
                    Layout.leftMargin: 10
                    Layout.rightMargin: 10
                }

                Label{
                    id: delayLable
                    text: "Delay[s]"
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.leftMargin: 10
                    Layout.rightMargin: 10
                }

                Slider{
                    id: delaySlider
                    from: 0.05
                    value: 0.1
                    to: 1
                    stepSize: 0.01
                    Material.foreground: controlsColor
                    Material.accent: controlsAccent
                    Material.elevation: controlsElevation
                    Layout.leftMargin: 10
                    Layout.rightMargin: 10
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    onValueChanged: function(){
                        Manager.delay = value;
                    }
                }

                Label{
                    id: incrementLable
                    text: "Increment"
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.leftMargin: 10
                    Layout.rightMargin: 10
                }

                Slider{
                    id: incrementSlider
                    from: 1.0
                    value: 1.0
                    to: 5.0
                    stepSize: 0.01
                    Material.foreground: controlsColor
                    Material.accent: controlsAccent
                    Material.elevation: controlsElevation
                    Layout.leftMargin: 10
                    Layout.rightMargin: 10
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    onValueChanged: function(){
                        Manager.xIncrement = value;
                    }
                }

                Item {
                    // spacer item
                    id: controlsSpacer
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Pane { anchors.fill: parent }//; Material.background: Material.Light; Material.elevation: 4 } // to visualize the spacer
                }

                Button{
                    id: startPointBtn
                    text: "START"
                    Material.foreground: controlsColor
                    Material.accent: controlsAccent
                    Material.elevation: controlsElevation
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.leftMargin: 10
                    Layout.rightMargin: 10
                    onClicked: function(){
                        console.log(text);
                        console.log(text=="START")
                        if(text=="START"){
                            Manager.starter = true;
                            Manager.dataReady.connect(drawPoint);
                            clearLine();
                            text = "STOP";
                        }
                        else{
                            Manager.starter = false;
                            text = "START";
                            Manager.dataReady.disconnect(drawPoint);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I do not know how to write the code. That's why I'm asking. I have found nothing about this topic and so I have no idea on how a connection between a signal from a python class and a slot on a qml file could be connected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use Connections but in the case of PySide/PySide2 you can not get the arguments so I'll use the trick they point to in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10507528/6622587).

If you are going to send a point then use QPoint as it is directly translated to point type in QML. You must also calculate the max and min to update the axes.

Considering the above, the solution is the following:

***.py**

```
import os
import sys
import time
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtQml

class Manager(QtCore.QObject):
    dataReady = QtCore.Signal(QtCore.QPointF, name='dataReady')

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Manager, self).__init__(parent)
        self._currX = 0
        self._currY = 0
        self._delay = 0.5
        self._multiplier = 1.0
        self._power = 1.0
        self._xIncrement = 1.0
        self._starter = False
        self._goOn = False
        self._threader = None

    @QtCore.Property(bool)
    def starter(self):
        return self._starter

    @starter.setter
    def starter(self, val):
        if self._multiplier == val:
            return
        print(val)
        if val:
            self.start()
        else:
            self.stop()
        self._starter = val

    @QtCore.Property(float)
    def multiplier(self):
        return self._multiplier

    @multiplier.setter
    def multiplier(self, val):
        if self._multiplier == val:
            return
        print(val)
        self._multiplier = val

    @QtCore.Property(int)
    def power(self):
        return self._power

    @power.setter
    def power(self, val):
        if self._power == val:
            return
        print(val)
        self._power = val

    @QtCore.Property(float)
    def delay(self):
        return self._delay

    @delay.setter
    def delay(self, val):
        if self._delay == val:
            return
        print(val)
        self._delay = val

    @QtCore.Property(float)
    def xIncrement(self):
        return self._xIncrement

    @xIncrement.setter
    def xIncrement(self, val):
        if self._xIncrement == val:
            return
        print(val)
        self._xIncrement = val

    def generatePoint(self):
        self._currX += self._xIncrement
        self._currY = self._multiplier*(self._currX**self._power)

        return self._currX,self._currY

    def stop(self):
        self._goOn = False
        if self._threader is not None:
            while self._threader.isRunning():
                time.sleep(0.1)

    def start(self):
        self._goOn = True
        self._threader = Threader(self.core, self)
        self._threader.start()

    def core(self):
        while self._goOn:
            p = QtCore.QPointF(*self.generatePoint())
            self.dataReady.emit(p)
            time.sleep(self._delay)

# -------------------------------------------------

class Threader(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self,core,parent=None):
        super(Threader, self).__init__(parent)
        self._core = core

    def run(self):
        self._core()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ["QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE"] = "Material"
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    manager = Manager()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(manager.stop)
    manager.start()
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
    ctx = engine.rootContext()
    ctx.setContextProperty("Manager", manager)
    engine.load('main.qml')
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtCharts 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    width:640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Simple ui")
    visible: true
    locale:locale

    property int controlsColor: Material.DeepPurple
    property int controlsAccent: Material.BlueGrey
    property real x: 0.0
    property int controlsElevation: 6
    property int paneElevation: 4

    signal reemitted(point p)
    Component.onCompleted: Manager.dataReady.connect(mainWindow.reemitted)
    onReemitted: {
        testXAxis.max = Math.max(testXAxis.max, p.x)
        testXAxis.min = Math.min(testXAxis.min, p.x)
        testYAxis.max = Math.max(testYAxis.max, p.y)
        testYAxis.min = Math.min(testYAxis.min, p.y)
        mainLine.append(p.x, p.y)
    }

    function drawPoint(xy){
        mainLine.append(xy[0],xy[1])
        if (mainWindow.x >= testXAxis.max){
            testXAxis.max = mainWindow.x;
        }
        if (py >= testYAxis.max){
            testYAxis.max = py;
        }
        if (py <= testYAxis.min){
            testYAxis.min = py;
        }
    }

    function clearLine(){
        mainLine.clear();
        mainLine.append(0,0);
    }

    Pane{
        id: mainPanel
        anchors.fill: parent
        //Material.theme: Material.Dark

        RowLayout{
            id: mainRowLO
            anchors.fill: parent
            spacing: 15

            //Chart pane
            Pane{
                id: chartPane
                Material.elevation: paneElevation
                //Material.background: Material.Grey
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.minimumHeight: 200
                Layout.minimumWidth: 400

                ChartView {
                    id: testChart
                    title: "Line"
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    antialiasing: true
                    LineSeries {
                        id: mainLine
                        name: "LineSeries"
                        axisX: ValueAxis{
                            id: testXAxis
                            min: 0.0
                            max: 2.0
                        }
                        axisY: ValueAxis{
                            id: testYAxis
                            min: 0.0
                            max: 2.0
                        }
                        XYPoint { x: 0; y: 0 }
                    }
                }
            }

            Pane{
                id: controlsPane
                Material.elevation: paneElevation
                //Material.background: Material.Grey
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.minimumHeight: 200
                Layout.minimumWidth: 200
                Layout.maximumWidth: 200

                ColumnLayout{
                    id: controlsColumnLO
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    spacing: 40

                    Label{
                        id: powerLabel
                        text: "Exponent"
                        Layout.topMargin: 40
                        Layout.leftMargin: 10
                        Layout.rightMargin: 10
                    }

                    SpinBox{
                        id: powerNum
                        from: 0
                        value: 1
                        to: 5
                        stepSize: 1
                        width: 80
                        validator: DoubleValidator {
                            bottom: Math.min(powerNum.from, powerNum.to)
                            top:  Math.max(powerNum.from, powerNum.to)
                        }
                        Material.foreground: controlsColor
                        Material.accent: controlsAccent
                        Material.elevation: controlsElevation
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.leftMargin: 10
                        Layout.rightMargin: 10
                        editable: true
                        onValueChanged: function(){
                            Manager.power = value;
                        }
                    }

                    Label{
                        id: multiplierLabel
                        text: "Multiplier"
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.leftMargin: 10
                        Layout.rightMargin: 10
                    }

                    Slider{
                        id: multiplierSlider
                        from: -50
                        value: 1
                        to: 50
                        Material.foreground: controlsColor
                        Material.accent: controlsAccent
                        Material.elevation: controlsElevation
                        Layout.leftMargin: 10
                        Layout.rightMargin: 10
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        onValueChanged: function(){
                            Manager.multiplier = value;
                        }
                    }

                    Label{
                        id: multValueLabel
                        text: String(multiplierSlider.value)
                        Layout.leftMargin: 10
                        Layout.rightMargin: 10
                    }

                    Label{
                        id: delayLable
                        text: "Delay[s]"
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.leftMargin: 10
                        Layout.rightMargin: 10
                    }

                    Slider{
                        id: delaySlider
                        from: 0.05
                        value: 0.1
                        to: 1
                        stepSize: 0.01
                        Material.foreground: controlsColor
                        Material.accent: controlsAccent
                        Material.elevation: controlsElevation
                        Layout.leftMargin: 10
                        Layout.rightMargin: 10
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        onValueChanged: function(){
                            Manager.delay = value;
                        }
                    }

                    Label{
                        id: incrementLable
                        text: "Increment"
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.leftMargin: 10
                        Layout.rightMargin: 10
                    }

                    Slider{
                        id: incrementSlider
                        from: 1.0
                        value: 1.0
                        to: 5.0
                        stepSize: 0.01
                        Material.foreground: controlsColor
                        Material.accent: controlsAccent
                        Material.elevation: controlsElevation
                        Layout.leftMargin: 10
                        Layout.rightMargin: 10
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        onValueChanged: function(){
                            Manager.xIncrement = value;
                        }
                    }

                    Item {
                        // spacer item
                        id: controlsSpacer
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: true
                        Pane { anchors.fill: parent }//; Material.background: Material.Light; Material.elevation: 4 } // to visualize the spacer
                    }

                    Button{
                        id: startPointBtn
                        text: "START"
                        Material.foreground: controlsColor
                        Material.accent: controlsAccent
                        Material.elevation: controlsElevation
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.leftMargin: 10
                        Layout.rightMargin: 10
                        onClicked: function(){
                            console.log(text);
                            if(text=="START"){
                                clearLine();
                                Manager.starter = true;
                                text = "STOP";
                            }
                            else{
                                Manager.starter = false;
                                text = "START";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: After some update (Qt or Fedora packaging, not sure) I only get `main.qml:216: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` whenever I try to set a property from QML. Does anyone have any idea why that is and what do do about it?

Comment: @dreua How did you install Qt and PySide2? What are the versions of both libraries?

Comment: `sudo dnf install qt-creator python3-pyside2` (Just tried it in a fresh Fedora 33 VM, same issue unfortunately. I am, however, sure that this worked before - maybe it was F32) Both Version 5.15.2, Python 3.9.0.

Comment: @dreua Maybe it's a bug, try creating a virtualenv and installing PySide2 using pip and verify that it doesn't work.

Comment: PySide2 from pip did not change anything. It still works, however, on Fedora Linux 32 (python3-pyside 5.15.0, qt 5.14.2, python 3.8.2)

Comment: @dreua I have just tested the latest version of PySide2 and reproduce the problem. Maybe I changed something internal in PySide2 or maybe it's a bug. When I have time I will analyze it and inform you of my conclusions

Comment: Turns out this is actually a regression in pyside2 from 5.15.1 to 5.15.2. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I just reported the regression: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1656

Comment: I just submitted an edit to fix the setter names, turns out they were never correct and it is unclear why it worked in previous pyside2 versions.